# How can I change img src's doamin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is HTML code like below

```
<img src="https://example.com/img_01.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_02.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_03.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_04.png">
```

I'd like to change these like:

```
<img src="https://example2.com/img_01.png">
<img src="https://example2.com/img_02.png">
<img src="https://example2.com/img_03.png">
<img src="https://example2.com/img_04.png">
```

How can I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` to change `url` inside loop to get new `url` like below.

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  newSrc = newSrc.replace('example', 'example2')
  $(this).attr('src', newSrc);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://example.com/img_01.png" />
<img src="https://example.com/img_02.png" />
<img src="https://example.com/img_03.png" />
<img src="https://example.com/img_04.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
$('img').attr('src',"https://example2.com/img_01.png");
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://example.com/img_01.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_02.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_03.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_04.png">
```

Comment: I can't edit manually i mean i need to change example.com to example2.com automatically

Comment: @Te Ggh what you mean by this. See the result of snippet the code the changed

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with jQuery:

```
<img src="https://example.com/img_01.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_02.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_03.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_04.png">
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("img").each(img => img.src.replace("example.com", "example2.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
var newDOmain = "https://example2.com/";

$('img').each(function(){
  var imgName = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop();
  $(this).attr('src', newDOmain + imgName);
  $(this).attr('alt', newDOmain + imgName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://example.com/img_01.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_02.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_03.png">
<img src="https://example.com/img_04.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

if some day ur url changes to "https://example.net/img_01.png" then u have to modify the code if u will use direct string replacements. So to make ur code more efficient use regex way to do the same.

```
var domainRegex = /\/{2,}((?:[^\.]+\.)*\w+)\//;
$("img").each(img => {
    img.src = img.src.replace(img.src.match(domainRegex)[1], "example2.com");
});
```

This regex can replace any domain name to ur chosen one.